# Why isn't phaser.js able to load an image from a third-party domain?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, phaser-framework

I'm learning `phaser.js`, and I cant even load the image.

Here is the code:

```
// Need state. All game logic goes in state

var GameState = {

    // Load all your images. Thats what the preload function is
    preload : function(){
        //Load Image
    this.load.image( 'background', 'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMxwX5oTml7qBFmUD3vEIzEhqLQfakBVjmkQezA8HKs4KnT-2Q' );

    },

    //Execute after everything is loaded
    create: function(){
        //From top left param = (x,y)
        this.background = this.game.add.sprite(0,0, 'background');

    },

    update: function(){


    }

}

// New Game instance, 3rd parameter WEBGL or CANVAS automatic  GL
var game = new Phaser.Game(640,360,Phaser.automatic);

// add state to game

// First just a name, second par is the actual Object
game.state.add('GameState', GameState);
game.state.start('GameState');
```

And here is the image that clearly shows that it doesen't load:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image isn't showing up because Phaser can't make use of cross-origin images, so all images need to be loaded from the same origin. In practice, this means that instead of loading the image directly from gstatic.com, you need to first download the image to your computer, then move it to your Phaser project folder and load it using a relative path.

For more information, please see the [Wikipedia article on the Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: @ewrwr That likely works because the proper cross-origin HTTP headers are set on the file on AWS, whereas in your example, the file on gstatic.com has no cross-origin headers set. In effect, Amazon AWS is saying "you're allowed to use this image even though you're on a separate domain", whereas gstatic.com doesn't say that, so it's disallowed by default. For more information, check out the [Wikipedia article on Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).